# CSS fixed scaling masthead, scrolling main, can't reach bottom text

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a pure CSS/HTML solution for a page that contains a fixed position header which shrink-sizes with its contents -even when changing font size in the browser- and a scrolling main that occupies the remainder of the window. The code below does most of what I want, but I can't see the whole text. 
In [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96mp9mvf/) you can't see or reach 'A text 20' or the last `<p>` once the window is small enough to necessitate scrolling. The two links in the html point to each others anchors; you can't reach the bottom one.

Most, if not all, solutions to similar questions use more than just pure HTML/CSS, which I want to avoid.

CSS:

```css
body,html{
    margin:0;padding:0;left:0;top:0;
    max-height:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#Wrapper{
    width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:green;
}
#mastheadChild{
    text-align:center;
    background-color:brown;
}
#mainWrapper {
    background-color:red;
    height:100%;
    max-height:100%;

}
#mainChild{
    background-color:blue;
    max-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
  }
a{
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
}
```

HTML:

```html
        <div id="Wrapper">
        <div id="mastheadChild">
                <p>This is a very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very wide masthead child </p>
        </div>
        <div id="mainWrapper">
            <div id="mainChild">
                    <h4>main scrolling</h4>
                    <p>This is a text, a <a href="#last">very</a>, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very wide text.</p>
                    <p>A text  1</p>
                    <p>A text  2</p>
                    <p>A text  3</p>
                    <p>A text  4</p>
                    <p>A text  5</p>
                    <p>A text  6</p>
                    <p>A text  7</p>
                    <p>A text  8</p>
                    <p>A text  9</p>
                    <p>A text  1</p>
                    <p>A text 10</p>
                    <p>A text 12</p>
                    <p>A text 13</p>
                    <p>A text 14</p>
                    <p>A text 15</p>
                    <p>A text 16</p>
                    <p>A text 17</p>
                    <p>A text 18</p>
                    <p>A text 19</p>
                    <p>A text 20</p>
                    <p id="last">link <a href="#mainChild">to first</a> text</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The content of wrapper is longer than wrapper itself, and there's no way to scroll your wrapper.

If you add a scroll to your wrapper:

`overflow-y:scroll`

You can then access the content outside the wrapper's view.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/96mp9mvf/2/

Comment: Thanks; almost there, at least we can reach the link at the bottom. Now there is a double scroll bar always visible. That eats real estate. Can we get rid of this too?

Comment: @user1789266 There are plugins out there which can replace the browser scroll, but I've not tried any of them.